# Double Action NSTableView Swift

Tags: nstableview

I'm working on a Mac application, using NSTableView.
Don't know why, but DoubleAction is not being called.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.setDataSource(self)
        tableView.setDelegate(self)
        getAllCountries()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        tableView.target = self

        let CL: Selector = "PerformDoubleClick:"
        tableView.doubleAction = CL

    }

    func PerformDoubleClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Selected")
    }
```